# How to update all the results after a SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

After I performed a SELECT query I use to show all the results on my page,
I wish to to UPDATE all the shots.views int column with +1 , 
which means everytime it shows these results it also updates the shots.views of it.

How do you guys think I should do this the best way and a little example? Of course I want to limit the amount of query's. I'm a little bit clueless right now. Thanks in advance!

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT 
shots.id,
shots.large, 
shots.title,
shots.datetime 

FROM notifications

INNER JOIN shots

ON notifications.target = shots.id

WHERE notifications.uid = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username') AND (notifications.type = 'picture' OR notifications.type = 'video' OR notifications.type = 'reshot')

ORDER BY datetime DESC

") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UPDATE` doesn't really return anything, I think you're stick to using two queries.  It was a noble goal, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value FROM counters WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE counters SET value = value + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

Thats what you're looking for :)